# Appropriateness of LDA for classification when majority of features are binary?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, discriminant-analysis

Am I correct in understanding that when using linear discriminant analysis, one assumes that the feature values are normally distributed?  If so, does this mean LDA is very poorly suited for data where the majority of features are binary (only 1 or 0)?  In this case, what would be a better method for multiclass classification?

Comment: If most are binary then a decision tree may be useful.